# Passing parammeters

Tags: programming-languages, dependency-injection, parameter-passing

Hi guys I have one question,

If I have a sequence of methods for example:

```
Main()
{
  Method1();
}

Method1()
{
  Method2();
}

Method2()
{
  Method3();
}

Method3()
{
  ObtainsUserPermission(httpContext.Current.User.Name);
}
```

How is the best way to do it, using the parammeter "httpContext.Current.User.Name" in the last Method3, or passing by parammeter in each method? Like this:

```
Main()
{
  Method1(httpContext.Current.User.Name);
}

Method1(string name)
{
  Method2(name);
}

Method2(string name)
{
  Method3(name);
}

Method3(string name)
{
  ObtainsUserPermission(name);
}
```

thank you for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like magic parameters.

A good rule of thumb is - if you wish your execution of method3() to depend on the name, pass the name as a parameter. In general, you shouldn't use globals inside functions. It can become complicated to debug and maintain. An exception is members of a class, in which case your members are visible inside the methods and there is no need to pass them as parameters.